# select branch_id from report group by branch_id order by max(date) desc to Django Query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-3.1

I have a model with the following fields

**id -> int**

**vivitor_id -> int**

**branch_id -> int**

**date -> datetime**

I need to perform the following query in Django. How to do this using Django ORM.

```
select branch_id from report group by branch_id order by max(date) desc ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proper Aggregation with values as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) so something in a line of

```
Report.objects.values('branch_id') 
    .annotate(max_date= Max('date'))
    .order_by('-max_date')
```